# How to create file for download using Response class and then interact with the client?

Tags: c#, javascript, response, window.open

I have a button and its `OnClientClick` event calls Generate().

```
function Generate() {
    window.open('GenerateKey.aspx', '_newtab', 'titlebar = no', false);
    PageMethods.SendKey(SendKeyCallback, SendKeyCallbackError);
}
```

The callbacks functions hide the loading gif and alert the status (success/failed)

GenerateKey.aspx creates a file and opens a download popup.

this is the page_load code:

```
    string keyFileName = orgName + "-" + timeStamp + ".ckey";
    fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/License/Generate/" + keyFileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.Write(generatedKey);
    sw.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + keyFileName);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/License/Generate/" + keyFileName));
    Response.End();
```

The code works fine, but my problem is that the new tab is closed after the download pops up to the screen (I guess it happens because of the Response object), and it looks like a bug.

I get popup of a new blank tab for 1 second and then it closed.

Anyone has an idea how to make it look better?
I can't do it on the same page, because after the file generation I don't have a connection to the client any more (that's why I used window.open).

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the browser to open a text file in another window.  The browser is probably interpreting the data as not HTML, storing the file to disk, and closing the window afterwards--that's fairly standard for browsers.  If that's not want you want, you need to send HTML data to the browser or configure your browser not to automatically save that type of data to disk.